# Hyper References in Latex

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I am using `hyperref` package for referencing but when i do references it gives me the chapter number instead of the label name and don't know why it is doing this as I am new to lateX. I searched a lots of example but nothing is working.

Here is my code

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width = 150mm]{flowChart.jpg}

\label{Figure:1}
\end{figure}
```

And for referencing

```
~\ref{Figure:1}
```

after this in PDF I am getting chapter number as 2.

Comment: You *must* place a `\caption` (*before* `\label` inside the `figure` environment) in order to have something to reference properly. How else should people know where to go and have a look at `\ref{Figure:1}`?

Comment: @Werner The reasoning behind your _how else_ is not clear. Thousands of people have had the same problem with captions inside figures and tables. The mechanism just isn't clear and/or prone to errors. I always recommend the label should be defined inside the caption. That way it will still work if the caption is moved.

Comment: You may try the package 'cleverref'.

Comment: A `figure` environment, by itself, generates no number: you might have more than one figure together with its caption in it, for instance, that you want to keep together. So it's `\caption` that generates the number.

Comment: This comes down to the same issue as the question I've linked to: you need a `\caption` before the `\label`.